# Python venv command shows error in windows

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv

when I try to create a virtual environment (for my Django project which I am new to) inside a folder using the python venv command as follows

python -m venv env

Then there is the following error "Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'" and if I check inside the same folder then the env folder is created but the activate file is not present inside the scripts folder. I have also checked the installed modules using pip list command and it shows that virtualenv and virtualenv-clone modules are present.
What's the way to resolve the error and I would be grateful if someone could explain the possible source of error?

Comment: have you tried different venv folder? I wonder if it doesn't like the name "env"

Comment: Yes, I have tried with venv, but it doesn't work at all. Finally, I switched to virtualenv instead of venv but the doc says it's depreciated command, but I had now way out.

Comment: Even with venv command, I got the environment created with the scripts folder having only the partial files (activate file was missing)